# Inner View Layout inside of DrawerLayout always returns FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawer

I have *LinearLayout* inside of *DrawerLayout* which renders drawer item and views according to layout_weight. I am trying to hide that view programmatically by setting its height to 0 or with *View.Visibility* - ***GONE*** property.

Tried

> - By setting its Visibilty as ***GONE*** it acts as *INVISIBLE*
> - By getting its LayoutParams and setting its height to 0. Though it acts as *INVISIBLE*

ParentLayout : *mother.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/activityMotherDrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_mother" />

    <include layout="@layout/motherdrawer" />

  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Layout : *motherdrawer.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.app.ui.view.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/drawerRootLayout"
  android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_mother_drawer_width"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  android:background="@color/background_application"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activityMotherDrawerInnerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_mother_drawer_layout_padding">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityMotherDrawerInnerInnerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activityMotherDrawerMyAttendanceLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activityMotherDrawerMyAttendanceIv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_mother_drawer_image_padding"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer_attendance" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/activityMotherDrawerMyAttendanceIv"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:text="@string/activity_mother_drawer_attendance"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_mother_drawer_text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activityMotherDrawerDashboardLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activityMotherDrawerDashboardIv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_mother_drawer_image_padding"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer_dashboard" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/activityMotherDrawerDashboardIv"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:text="@string/activity_mother_drawer_dashboard"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_mother_drawer_text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activityMotherDrawerSettingsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activityMotherDrawerSettingsIv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_mother_drawer_image_padding"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer_settings" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/activityMotherDrawerSettingsIv"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:text="@string/activity_mother_drawer_setting"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_mother_drawer_text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
 </com.app.ui.view.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>`
```

Whenever I tried to fetch the layoutParam using **getLayoutParams** it returns ***FrameLayout*** where its ParentView is LinearLayout.

Using Java :

```
mDashboardLayout = (LinearLayout)mDrawerInnerRootLayout.findViewById(R.id.activityMotherDrawerDashboardLayout);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mDashboardLayout.getLayoutParams();//returns FrameLayout instead where it should return LinearLayout

mDashboardLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); //it acts as INVISIBILITY
```

> Can anyone enlighten me why it returns *FrameLayout instead of
>   **LinearLayout*** Or Why its Visibility changes to INVISIBLE instead of GONE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though changing View - Visibility to either `GONE` or `INVISIBLE` still View is always INVISIBLE. It does accept onClick event. As per SO, I want to completely remove that view. I am able to achieve it using following method.

I am adding View to ParentView hierarchy accordingly programmatically and refreshing the whole layout.

```
  View inflatedDashboardView;
  inflatedDashboardView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_drawer_dashboard, mDrawerInnerRootLayout, false);
  mDashboardLayout = (LinearLayout) inflatedDashboardView.findViewById(R.id.activityMotherDrawerDashboardLayout);
  mDrawerInnerRootLayout.addView(inflatedDashboardView);
  mDrawerInnerRootLayout.forceLayout();
```

Still I'm not able to understand why InnerView Layout inside of DrawerLayout always return FrameLayout.